# Improving Wireless Router Performance

Tags: router, wifi

I bought an Asus RT-N53 wifi router, and I'm having nightmarish performance issues with it. I have WPA2/AES encryption enabled, and I can connect to it from from an Ubuntu 12.04 laptop, but after a few minutes the network becomes completely unresponsive.

The connection doesn't appear to get dropped or disconnected (e.g. Network Manager shows it's still connected), but ping and traceroute just hang. If I do nothing, it seems to fix itself after 5-10 minutes, but it's infuriating to have my Internet connection randomly disappear. If I use a wired connection, this doesn't happen, so it's definitely not a problem with my actual Internet connection. If I manually turn my laptop's wifi on and off, the connection immediately comes back.

How would I diagnose what's causing this?

Comment: You bought a piece of shit consumer router.  Tough luck.  Buy something better next time around.  Cisco/Meraki/Aruba/Xirrus/Brocade

Comment: @TomO'Connor, That's not a helpful comment. I had Cisco router previously, and had equally horrible performance.

Comment: It's an Asus.  Serverfault is a community for professional server, networking and related infrastructure. Asus are none of those.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check:

- Signal strenght changing router or client position
- Change WiFi signal channel
- Try to use WiFi with another device and another OS if is possible
- Double check your configuration, thinking that some notebooks are not completely support 802.11n, so try also 802.11g configuration
- Change the authentication in WPA(2)/PSK